# CakePHP render different layout-file from internal / external link

Tags: cakephp, view, render, cakephp-2.1

In my project, I'm displaying my views in a lightbox and I don't want the top-navigation to be loaded.
I'm using:

> $this->render('ajax');

That way, only the content is loaded and it looks nice inside the lightbox.

The problem is, when I share the view-link.

Clicking the view-link only shows the view page **WITHOUT** top-navigation (etc.)

***Any idea, how I could change the render-value only for the view-method?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is where the request handler comes in to play.

Try something like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->render('ajax');

} else {
    $this->layout = 'regular_layout';
    $this->render('not_ajax');
}
```

When accessing `app/controller/action` directly, the "non-ajax" view/layout will be rendered instead.

[More in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html).

Comment: nice solution, very straight forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use $this->referer() to see if the user came from your site or another site, if they came from another site (external) then either render a different view or just redirect the user to another page .. you could do the same thing with sessions rather than refereeing address, checking if the user has a session (you would have had to set previously) ...

Comment: Thank you, depending on the project, this might also be a nice way.

Comment: No worries. Upon reflection, I'd use Ross' solution :D